# Ruby on Rails: How can i iterate over params and convert any empty strings into nil values in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

Rails newbie here.

I have an integration with stripe where users can update the billing address on their card, however, stripe doesn't accept empty strings, only nil values, and it's possible that users won't need to fill in the second address line for example.

How would I go about iterating through params received from a form and convert empty strings into nil?

I have a Stripe Tool module that handles stripe related tasks.

In my controller i have:

```
   def add_billing_address
   account_id = current_user.account_id
   account = Account.find_by(id: account_id)
   stripe_id = account.stripe_customer_id
# convert params empty strings to nil here
   StripeTool.add_billing_address(stripe_id: stripe_id,
                                stripe_token: params[:stripeToken],
                                address_line1: params[:address_line1],
                                address_line2: params[:address_line2],
                                address_city: params[:address_city],
                                address_state: params[:address_state],
                                address_zip: params[:address_zip]
                                )
# redirects and error handling happens after this
```

Comment: Can you tell what params you want to iterate over, and what you want to do with that? (like, stocking it inside a variable or in an array, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to avoid modifying the values in the params object, cause it is not good practice to change them in place. It is better to create a new object the has the values you want to use.

```
stripe_params = params.select { |_,v| v.present? }
```

This will create a new object without any of the blank attributes. I'm guessing that if an attribute is nil, you might as well not pass it at all.

Comment: Yeah, this also makes complete sense. Solution works perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can call <s>.map</s> .each on the params hash in the controller like this:

```
params.each do |key, value|
  params[key] = nil if value === ''
end
```

But it's probably better to let your form return a nil value when a field contains no data.

Comment: Stripe specifically requires 'nil' but my params look like this for example: {"address_line2"=>"", "address_city"=>"Amsterdam", }

Went with DanneManne's solution as it makes sense for my use case. But this was also helpful to know. Thank you.